# Python 3 for Revit 2022: typeerror: instance property must be accessed through a class insctance

Tags: python, revit-api

I`m converting a python 2.7 script to python 3. The script is used in Dynamo for Revit 2022.
In 2.7 the code works but in python 3 it gives a typeerror: instance property must be accessed through a class insctance. Can anyone help with this?

```
def Typenaam_Family(itm):
    Typenaam = []
    Collector_Element_And_Typename = []
    Bcat = itm[0]
    Dict_Element_And_Typename = itm[1]
    Collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(Bcat).WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()
        
        
    for itm in Collector:
        
        Typenaam.append(Element.Name.GetValue(itm)) 
            
    Collector_Element_And_Typename.extend(list(zip(Typenaam,Collector)))
        
    for itm in Collector_Element_And_Typename:
        
        Dict_Element_And_Typename[itm[0]] = itm[1]

Benodigde_Categorys = [[BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors,Dict_Door_Element_And_Typename],[BuiltInCategory.OST_PlumbingFixtures,Dict_Plumbing_Element_And_Typename],[BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls,Dict_Wall_Element_And_Typename],[BuiltInCategory.OST_Floors,Dict_Floor_Element_And_Typename],[BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns,Dict_Kolommen_Liggers_Element_And_Typename],[BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralFraming,Dict_Kolommen_Liggers_Element_And_Typename]] 
    
for itm in Benodigde_Categorys:
    Typenaam_Family(itm)
```

I tried

```
___get___
```

instead of .GetValue but that didn`t solve.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```py
Typenaam.append(Element.Name.GetValue(itm))
```

to this:

```
Typenaam.append(itm.get_Name())
```

In theory it should work as `itm.Name`, but then it raise error that interperer can't read value. `itm.Name` works in RevitPythonShell, but Dynamo has it's `itm.get_Name()`. I have no idea why they did such implementation, but probably due to .NET compability.

Tested only on Revit 2023.1/Dynamo 2.16.1